# Inetpub -acces denied?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web, directory

I am trying to develop an asp application(my asp solution is in c:\inetpub). i need a logger.
So I create inside my solution a folder Logs and I try to save there a *.log file:

```
   using (FileStream fs = File.Create(logPath))
        {...}
  // logpath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Logs") + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + logName
  // so: logpath =  C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MyApplication\\Logs\\MyLog.log
```

I get the error:

```
 Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication\Logs\MyLog.log' is denied.
```

Is there a solution for this? I need that the installer to be able to  provide acces to inetpub...
I am asking also if is this the wrong way to create a log? Maybe exist a pattern used for that ...? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the write permission to the asp.net user. Typically it is `Network Service` or `IUSR`.

If you are running IIS7 make sure to check the `Identity` under advanced `settings` of the application pool.

For more information look into this: [Application Pool Identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the inetpub directory allows read/write permissions to the built in `IUSR` account.

Comment: could you please explain this ? (I am not very familiar with IIS manager, I had  a look but not understand what I should do.). Thanks in advance